# Parallelisation of Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline (in YAML) which upgrades an infrastructure(I have 2 stages each containing a series of jobs)

I now want to upgrade multiple infrastructures simultaneously i.e. pass a list of identifiers which represents deployments to the pipeline and then let it upgrade each.

What is the best practice here for organising the pipeline? It feels like I need to generate a set of parallel jobs using a loop?

As I understand it any job failure will result in a total failure which could leave us in a very confused state.

Comment: Search for `strategy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#job

Comment: Have you used this  (Im assuming youre directing me towards matrix) where the inputs are dynamically set i.e. I pass in a set of infrastructure identities 1,2,3,50 to represent the infrastructures I want updating?

Comment: how are the infrastructure identities dynamically set in your pipeline? Do you set the identities in the first stage and pass the identities to the second stage to upgrade?

Comment: The person executing the pipeline will enter them as a parameter

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below template, how did it go?

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased [parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops) for your organization. You can use [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) to generate multiple jobs according the identities parameter using expression `${{each id in parameters.identities}}`.

So you can move the job which upgrades the infrastructures into a template and define your yaml pipeline as below. See below example:

**Template file: upgrade-infrastructure.yml**

```
parameters:
  id: 1
  
jobs:
- job: upgradeinfra${{parameters.id}}

  steps:
  - powershell: echo "upgrade-infra-${{parameters.id}}"
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**:

```
#define the identities as a object to hold a array object of ids
parameters:
- name: identities 
  type: object
  default:
    ids:
    - 1
    - 2


trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Upgrage
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest
  
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - powershell: echo "job A"    
  
  #loop through the ids array object and the each id to the template paramter to generate multiple jobs for each id.
  #indentation is very important, bad indentation may cause pipeline compile error.
  - ${{ each id in parameters.identities.ids }}:
    - template: upgrade-infrastructure.yml
      parameters: 
        id: ${{id}}
```

After you set up your yaml pipeline as above, you can enter the identities in the parameter when executing the pipeline:

[image]

Then you will see the multiple jobs are generated and run in parallel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make your deployments run in parallel, all you need to do is to set the dependencies. (The dependency on the previous step is automatically set). Here is an example of a stage that only depends on the build before all stage will run in parallel:

```
stage:
   -stages : DeployTo${{ parameters.environment }}
     dependsOn: ["Build"] //The stage that build the code is called "Build"
```

The Result looks like this:
[image]

Without the dependsOn property your pipeline stages will run sequentially and looks like this:

```
stages:
   -stage : DeployTo${{ parameters.environment }}
```

[image]